Проблема с подключением к сети в питоне
Пишу код для смены MAC-адреса, при подключении к проводной сети код работает без ошибок, при подключении к беспроводной ошибка:

ERROR - Failed to re-enable the network interface: Command 'netsh interface set interface "IDK" admin=enable' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Причем постоянно.
def change_mac_address(interface, new_mac):
    try:
        # Disable the network interface
        subprocess.check_call(f'netsh interface set interface "{interface}" admin=disable', shell=True)
        key = r'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001'
        # Change the MAC address in the registry
        subprocess.check_call(f'reg add "{key}" /v NetworkAddress /d {new_mac} /f', shell=True)
        # Enable the network interface
        subprocess.check_call(f'netsh interface set interface "{interface}" admin=enable', shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to change MAC address: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        # Attempt to re-enable the interface even if the operation fails
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(f'netsh interface set interface "{interface}" admin=enable', shell=True)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to re-enable the network interface: {e}")

вот кусочек кода, из-за которого идет ошибка

а причем здесь, собственно, python?

А хоть какими-нибудь другими средствами вам удается его заменить?

"ERROR - Failed to re-enable the network interface: Command 'netsh interface set interface "IDK" admin=enable' returned non-zero exit status 1." — подозреваю, что дело не в коде, а в подключении

Проверяйте ключ на корректность и отлаживайте ‍♂️
